# Run Time/Time complexity when i=srqt(i) in each iteration

Tags: python, loops, runtime, sqrt

```
i=n 
while i>1 :
    i = int(math.sqrt(i))
    print('*')
```

why is the time complixity of the code above log(log(n)) ??
(Assume sqrt() runs in O(1).)

Comment: no it doesn't run n times since i is squarerooted each time. n=16: you get 4 2 1.

Comment: I think these two links relates to this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798251/running-time-time-complexity-for-while-loop-with-square-root
 
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6901/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-the-following-program

Comment: @stormfield the while loop is not repeated n times that's the whole point of my question , in the question  we "assume" that the runtime complexity of the sqrt function is o(1) , i know the answer (o(log(log(n)))), i just can't explain why ...

Comment: Apologies for jumping the gun earlier. :)

Comment: that's not related that's an exact duplicate

Comment: :D well then upvote the comment  :D

Comment: of course. Next time you can flag as duplicate. This saves time.

Answer (score 1):

Assume n can be coded with k bits.

After first iteration, i=√n and i can be coded on k/2 bits.

Hence the number of bits required to code i is divided by 2 at every step and the number of steps is log(k).

As k=log(n), complexity is log(log(n)), if we assume that sqrt complexity is one.